# html link column in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible have a html link in a column with jqGrid, I can't find any example in the documentation?

Comment: @djangofan jQuery and ExtJs are two different frameworks and have nothing to do with grids. I don't understand what your comment has to do with this question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, use a formatter, either a custom formatter or [Predefined Formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter).

Comment: link with the answer is broken

Comment: link has since been fixed

Answer (score 31):

Here's the sample colModel configuration from Craig's link to jqGrid formatting help. It specifies the formatter as **showLink** and the url and params are specified with **formatoptions**.

```
colModel: [ {name:'myname', 
             edittype:'select', 
             formatter:'showlink', 
             formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'someurl.php', addParam: '&action=edit'}
```

Comment: It appends id=bla to base url, can I change the id to something else like data_id or record_id? I found how to do this formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'someurl.php', addParam: '&action=edit', idName='record_id'}

Answer (score 23):

Sorry to post to an old question, but here is another option that worked for me: simply create a [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) and return an anchor tag (a good option if you need really granular control of the link):

```
function returnMyLink(cellValue, options, rowdata, action) 
{
    return "<a href='/Controller/Action/" + options.rowId + "' >Click here</a>";
}
```

Look in the rowdata for the data returned by your query.  Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Use this one where you want the id part of the link and not a parameter.  eg. you want /mylink/123/ not /mylink?id=123

Comment: this approach with custom formater will require further work in editoptions cause full output will be put in there as value.

Answer (score 4):

within the json data i am using for the grid, i just send html code back with a href tag in, that works for me

Comment: Worked for me.  In MVC controller action something like this when creating the json object worked for me: `@"<a href=""" + Url.Content("~/People/Details/" + p.PeopleKey.ToString()) + @""">" + p.Name + "</a>"`
This however breaks the sorting as it encounter PeopleKey before Name.  But I'm sure there is another work around for this.

Comment: Managed to fix the sorting.  Have to add another column that is just the text to sort on which is hidden 
`{ name: 'Name', index: 'Name', hidden: true},`
 and then reference that column name in the visible column's index:
`{width: 190, name: 'NameUrl', index: 'Name'},`

Answer (score 3):

If you use xml data, you can add a dummy column in your query to display it in the grid

grid:

```
colModel :[{name:'EDIT',edittype:'select',formatter:'showlink', width:5,xmlmap:"Edit",formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'someurl.php', addParam: '&action=edit'}},
```

query:

```
select f1,f2,f3, 'Edit' as Edit FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

in xml I use  entity &lt; instead of < in the a tag like this
&lt;a href="dest">my link&lt;/a> and works fine with jqgrid 3.6