# how to display hyperlinks in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm new to jQGrid. Is it possible to display hyperlinks in the columns of jqGrid? In our UI, we need to display Edit and Delete links next to each row of the table. is it possible with jqGrid?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166076/html-link-column-in-jqgrid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at : [this](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter). There are two predefined format types which may be usefull for you - link and showlink.

Rio's solution should work too but using formatters is much better (in my oppinion)

Best regards

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is. Send your JSON response back containing the link (from my example on jqgrid.com). For example:

```
{"page":"1","total":4,"records":"22","rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["<a href='linkhere'>Quantum of Solace</a>","Marc Forster","2008","Daniel Craig","200]}]}
```

Comment: Whilst this would work, it is a generally poor methodology to need to encode your URLs in your JSON responses.