# Create a jqGrid link with just the id

Tags: jqgrid, hyperlink, formatter

I [can see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166076/html-link-column-in-jqgrid) how to create a jqGrid link using:

```
colModel: [ {name:'myname', 
             formatter:'showlink', 
             formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'someurl.php', addParam: '&action=edit'}
```

This creates a request like `/someurl.php?id=XX&action=edit` and the display text will be the value of `myname`.

But in our case we don't need the `myname` text - our display text will be hard coded.  We don't want to have to pass any additional data down in our JSON request - but it seems you need a JSON attribute for each column.  How can we have a link without the add'l JSON column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatter `'showlink'` like all other formatter are used **to format the data loaded in jqGrid** from server or from the local data. So in case of your example you will not have 'myname' text (the column name) in the link but **the cell value** from the grid.

So if you want to use [predefined formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) `'showlink'` you have **to fill the column data** with the text which want to see in the link. You can do this either inside of your JSON data or filling/overwriting the text after the page are loaded for example inside of [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handle:

```
loadComplete: function() {
    var grid = $("list");
    var ids = grid.getDataIDs();
    for (var i = 0, idCount = ids.length; i < idCount; i++) {
        grid.setCell(id, 'myname', 'My text for link');
    }
}
```

You can use also [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) and [custom unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) instead of `'showlink'` [predefined formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types). Then you can define the text of link like you want without filling any data in the grid.